# Using imshow and twiny: cannot set xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I am trying to plot an image and some lines over it using pyplot. Also, I need to have two x-axes, one on the bottom and one on the top. Let's say the lower one should have five ticks and range from 0 to 5, and the upper one should also have five ticks, but range from 36 to 41, and these ticks should be aligned. This is easily done by:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.axis([0,5,10,20])      # set bottom axis limits
plt.grid()
ax2 = plt.twiny()
ax2.axis([36,41,10,20])    # set top axis limits
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

However, once I use `imshow`, I cannot seem to be able to set the limits of the bottom x axis correctly:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Using a small checkerboard as image
a = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.axis([0,5,10,20])     # Set lower axis limits -> are ignored
ax1.imshow(a, extent=(0,5,10,20))
plt.grid()
ax2 = plt.twiny()         # If these two lines are commented
ax2.axis([36,41,10,20])   # imshow behaves as expected
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

How can I display an image while keeping the ticks at axes aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two contradicing contraints here:

- The limits set to the axes.
- The equal aspect ratio of the image.

You may loosen one of those, i.e. if you want to specify the limits, make the aspect automatic,

```
ax1.imshow(a, extent=(0,5,10,20), aspect="auto")
```

[image]